# How can I dynamically add EJS-containing page elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have some data from a MySQL DB that I pass to the EJS template when I render it with Express. From that data I need to be able to create a selector element, with the option for the user to add more selector elements (with the same data). I also need a way to somehow identify each selector (I have tried to do this by assigning a variable as part of the id and name attributes of the selector, when generating it in jQuery) so that I can later hand all of them back to the database and create entries in another table based on the data received.

However, when I try to re-use EJS variables, the code doesn't get generated but rather I just get the EJS code back as text. I understand that this is because EJS is rendered by the server so I can't use it in the same way on the front-end; however, I have been unable to find an explanation on how to go about this problem. I'm new to Node and EJS, as well as back-end programming in general, so any help would be appreciated.

HTML code for the initial selector and add button:

```
<div class="form-group" id="tasks-form">
  <label>Tasks</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="task1" name="task1">
    <% tasktypes.forEach (function (tasktype) { %>
      <option value="<%- tasktype.taskid %>"><%- tasktype.description %></option>
    <% }); %>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-task">Add Task</button>
</div>
```

JS/JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var formsAllowed = 20;
  var currentForms = 1;

  $('#add-task').click(function(){
    if (currentForms < formsAllowed) {
      currentForms ++;
      $('#tasks-form').append('\
        <select class="form-control" id="task' + currentForms + '" name="task' + currentForms + '"> \
          <% tasktypes.forEach (function (tasktype) { %> \
           <option value="<%- tasktype.tasktypeid %>"><%- tasktype.description %></option> \
          <% }); %> \
        </select>  \
        ');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your select elements are always the same, can you just clone the original select box using a jquery function like this one?

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

and then use JavaScript to assign a new id attribute to the newly cloned element?

I'm not super familiar with jQuery, but it seems like a logical option.

If, however, you don't want to have exactly the same options in your select box, then you need to make sure that all of the data you need is loaded into your HTML page when it renders.

My approach would be to store your data as JSON and store it in a hidden element in the DOM (input fields are good for this, as you can just use the value attribute). You can then access your data using regular frontend JavaScript.

Comment: Hiya, sorry for the late reply - decided to store the data in JSON and it worked. Thanks for the help!